# I've got the world, story and scenes...where do I go from there to make them real?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

More of a do and show person, not really good with words.

Got movies in my head and remember them for years to the most miniscule detail...as If I was inside them.

Collected memories seen through the eyes of victims, heroes and villains.

tried drawing, can't seem to figure it out. Been studying 2D and 3D art by myself for the last 4 years and I might be a slow one but I'm barely at a mediocre level when it comes to skill.

Starting to wonder if invisting more years of my life to get decent at hobby will ever be worth it, and if I will ever get decent at it, heard plenty about people who reach a bedrock limit in their skill and I've got the feeling mine is close.

tried acting, quite good at it, when pretending I actually feel the emotions I'm acting out, can cry at will and more, but not enough to become a movie director anytime soon.

Wondering if there was any courses that teaches arts for slow people and maybe in a way that I can actually practice directly on my  fictional worlds...and not repeating over and over again paints of fruits and dead flowers for days until I learn to draw them by memory (as art books demand) , but skills I can directly apply to worldbuilding as I learn them.

So when it comes to drawing, I can't draw anything that I haven't practiced for a few dozen hours at least. And even that doesn't show the best results.

And when it comes to 3D art, this seems easier but shading and colouring is 2D so shares the problems of normal drawing, everytime I've got to color something new I have to first invest a lot of time to study and practice it.

Considered giving up and just paying people make my world real or at least into real shapes, colors and animations.

In this last case how and where would one find the artists for that and how would it work out? Is a manager needed for that?

Comment: Is this about worldbuilding or about writing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @L.Dutch implemtations of visual arts to worldbuilding.

Comment: I think this needs to be migrated to Writing SE, but I'm not sure you want it to be about writing. Maybe you need to find a collaborator, like a graphic artist, to work with. Only then you'd be sharing any proceeds, because I think you need a true partner.

Comment: you can order art on freelance sites, describing in a way you can, and then use it to see if you can build upon that, how people can react, and all that. Depends on the form and what it is specifically, there are examples where people are capable to tow it alone as storytelling and borrowing stuff from different free license stuff as an illustration, but in general, it requires skills if you interested in visuals from scratch. Look for blender communities and similar for help in animation and visuals. Look for a writer, maybe, as well, again freelance sites, communities.

Comment: This seems like a *Process of Worldbuilding* query. It seems sufficiently interesting and broadly applicable that I'd like to see it remain open and get some answers.

Comment: VTO: Do agree with @elemtilas, maybe formulation and such isn't the greatest, anyone is free to make an edit - but in the essence it is a q - how do I bring my ideas/work to a next level. Time to share some practical or theoretical expirience, places etc. It can be useful  for other people, as this user basically asking - how do I do that from scratch, how start to share what I envision with other people, how start to expand beyond myself. That a bridge to cross for plenty/enough of people.

Comment: It is indeed hard to understand what the OP wants to ask and the query would benefit from editing (give it more structure and clarity). However, I agree with elemtilas that this is an interesting Process of Wordbuilding question.

Comment: I am actually facing the same issues oftentimes. The question is relatively simple and is the one in title, however, I believe all the fluff that makes this question unclear is due to the inner doubts when looking at the monstruous task of creating a setting. @Getae I'm suggesting to ask only about how can "you", personally can bring up your world alive, rather than about hiring someone else. I feel it should be far more interesting to you, as it looks to me more like a mental lock to break than a lack of manpower ;). Willing to reopen under the condition of refocusing the question.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest: just do it. Write them, film them, draw them.

What you are concerned with is ... quality. You are internally saying "How can I compete? I can't make things good enough".

I'm here to tell you:

1. The first few always suck. Ask any artist.
2. Quality matters less than you think. Doing is what matters. One of my favourite web comics is "A Miracle of Science". The art is a long way from perfect, but it's still a great world and a great story.
3. You'll get better by doing. Look at the first few XKCD's, compare thrm to current. Look at the first few Wilde Life, compare them to now. Read the first story by Asimov, compare it to his greatest.
4. Don't be afraid to ask for others to help you, but you have to sell them your idea.

Comment: ...or pay them for their skilled assistance.

Comment: "Quality matters less than you think." Seriously. Just ask [Scott Adams](https://dilbert.com/).